# Joomla adds / to empty href and src attribute

Tags: joomla-3.x, component

I have a mustache template and the output via php is:

```
<a href="{{link}}"><img src="{{image}}" title="{{name}}" alt="{{name}}"></a>
```

but Joomla renders my output to:

```
<a href="/{{link}}"><img src="/{{image}}" title="{{name}}" alt="{{name}}"></a>
```

so all links are filled with mustache are wrong.

How can I disable this?

UPDATE: I found that /plugins/system/sef/sef.php up to line 118 are made this change.
But how can I change it without change anything in the core files?

Comment: Hi Lovntola! I feel the information given in your question is very little and vague. Is this a custom template? Have you done everything needed for the implementation? Is it only for the {{links}}? Also when you say Joomla renders your output like "/{{link} you mean it does render it like this, or the {{inBrankets}} part is outputting the actual content of the variable? *PS I don't have any recent real experience with mustache though...

Comment: Sorry for my bad description. I check the php output und it is href="{{link}}" but the source code in the browser shows href="\{{link}}". This is before mustache starts to work. It is the pure source code without any mustache impact.

Comment: Shorter: It is the same if you write <a href="">test</a> in the source code of a article. The output in the source code is: <a href="/">test</a>

Comment: Hmm Ok - this comes from the core system SEF plugin. Why is it a problem? What finally happens to your links?

Comment: @FFrewin Sorry I'am not familar with writing plugin for SYSTEM. Can I write a system plugin what change this setting back ( like regex  /{{ to {{ ), or is this a bad idea for further updates?

Comment: Not necessarily a bad idea - but still I am not sure why the core functionality of the SEF plugin is a problem for you. What has been the real actual problem you are facing? I haven't seen this being a problem so far, why is it constitutes one for you now? What should your {{link}} output that the SEF plugin will alter?

Comment: Mustache change the href="{{link}}" to href="http://...". so after SEF change the href to href="/{{link}}" mustache convert it to href="/http://..." and the browserlink is now: http://mydomain/http://link.

Comment: @FFrewin FYI here is what i realy do: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-list/ in my Joomla Template.

Comment: oh... so if I got it right with my quicklook, the {{link}} gets replaced later on the browser?? if so, then that's a problem at least for external links

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Problem is the SEF Plugin. So I don't want to modify a core Plugin, so I wrote a new Plugin that makes the changes only for the mustache template back.
!!! Importent that the new plugin must execute after the SEF Plugin
Here is my code sample to replace the / for the {{name}}

```
public function onAfterRender()
    {
        if (!$this->app->isClient('site'))
        {
            return;
        }

        $buffer = $this->app->getBody();
        $buffer = str_replace('/{{', '{{', $buffer);
            $this->app->setBody($buffer);
    }
```